# Running "java ivy.IVYbot.IVYbot.Main" in target/classes directory returns cannot find main class error

Tags: java, maven, jar

I'm trying to use the Windows command line to run my class files. However, when I try to run it, nothing ever works and I only see the

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main.
```

I've tried several different solutions all around this site. (The class file I want is located in target/classes/ivy/IVYbot/IVYbot/Main.class.)

```
> C:\Users\Ivy\Documents\GitHub\IVYbot\target\classes> java ivy.IVYbot.IVYbot.Main
Error: Could not find or load main class ivy.IVYbot.IVYbot.Main

> C:\Users\Ivy\Documents\Github\IVYbot> java -cp .;.\target\classes Main
Error: Could not find or load main class Main.

> C:\Users\Ivy\Documents\Github\IVYbot> java -cp .;.\target\classes ivy.IVYbot.IVYbot.Main
Error: Could not find or load main class ivy.IVYbot.IVYbot.Main.

> C:\Users\Ivy\Documents\Github\IVYbot\target\classes\ivy\IVYbot\IVYbot> java Main
Error: Could not find or load main class Main.
```

I even tried compiling the entire thing into a .jar file through Maven (with dependencies).

```
> C:\Users\Ivy\Documents\Github\IVYbot\target> java -jar IVYbot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
no main manifest attribute, in IVYbot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

though it should, as

```
> C:\Users\Ivy\Documents\Github\IVYbot\target> jar tf IVYbot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
...
```

shows. I have no idea what's wrong with my pathing. The plugin that I'm using for my Maven, if that's useful:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have compiled with the maven plugin and assembled the jar with its dependency, you can run your class using the following command:

```
java -cp IVYbot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar ivy.IVYbot.IVYbot.Main
```

Otherwise, if you want to run only the class that you have compiled you can use the following command, but remember to be in the directory where the compiled class is:

```
java -cp . Main
```

This because you have to specify the classpath in order to execute your class and the `.` tells java to use the current directory as classpath.